# Make an xpath balanced with braces

Tags: xpath

I have a string (ideally an xpath) which I need to parse and balance the opening and closing braces like '(' , ')' , '[' , ']'

Ex: //view/section/row[(cell/data[@value='Other Roles']) and (cell/data[contains(@value,'336')]) and (cell/data[contains(@value,'0')]) and (cell/data[contains(@value,'320')]) and (cell/data[contains(@value,'16')]) and (cell/data[contains(@value,'0')]) and (cell/data[contains(@value,'0')]) and (cell/data[contains(@value,'0')]) and (cell/data[contains(@value,'0')]) and (cell/data[contains(@value,'0')]) and (cell/data[contains(@value,'0')]) and (cell/data[contains(@value,'0')])

Can you please suggest an optimized solution to add the braces or parenthesis accordingly so that xpath works

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to balance while you are coding? So it would be a job for your editor/IDE wouldn't it? Some tools are capable of this. I'm a little confused with your example, though. Why do you add the same condition `cell/data[contains(@value,'0')]` eight times?

Comment: I am splitting my original xpath on some regex and I get the above string mentioned in ex. So I have to handle this to build a new xpath with balanced braces. I don not want my IDE do this, which will not help, I have to do that in my java code. Coming to the condition , it is not same condition, I have a row with 8 different cell with different values for each.Please sugges

Comment: @sam6 Marcus is right, it is the same condition. You are not accessing any specific cell, you are always querying all cells in that row. Also, in your example I see no non-balanced braces. Furthermore, this would be a non-trivial problem, e.g. how would you decide whether `(/test[]` should be `(/test[])` or `(/test)[]`? That would both be valid, but semantically different.